# characters in terminal not 100% white and backgournd is not 100% black on terminator window on xfce4

Tags: unity, xubuntu, fonts, xfce, brightness

I use two machines often using vnn. One is ubuntu 20.04 unity the other is ubuntu 22.04 xfce4.
I used terminator window on both systems.
But in the xfce4 case, the character is not 100% white and the black is not 100% black. The contrast isn't big enough so it always looks a little dimmed. But in the unity case, it is clear and more comfortable to my eyes. I tried to change the font color in the terminator's preference window but couldn't find the menu(only unfocused terminal font brightness setting is there. And in Profiles tab, 'use the system fixed width font' is checked, I tried setting it to another font, but it didn't make big difference). I tried to find it in the 'Desktop' settings but there was no font setting.
How can I give the fonts in xfce more contrast? (100% white characters on 100% black backgroud on the terminal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminator, go to preferences, then select the profiles tab, select a profile (e.g., "default") and then select the color tab.

You can either try different built in color schemes, or customize the colors and alter individual colors.

Changing the font won't help the colors, but you might want to select a bold font.

Comment: Yes, I just found the same and changed the 'built-in shcems' from 'gray on black' to 'white on black'.  I think in my old ubuntu 20-04 machine I've chaged that before. Thank you.